# How to get Openid for google account

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, openid, google-openid

I am developing a Spring MVC webapp that has Spring security enabled. I am trying to use OpenID to use gmail login for access to the webapp given instructions [here](http://krams915.blogspot.in/2011/02/spring-security-3-openid-login-with_13.html).

I want only a specific set of users to have access to webapp. For this, I would be required to add all the users and their ID's to  tag. (Later will implement a DB access for this)

My question is: **How can I find the OpenID for my gmail account that will be used to access the webapp?**

I understand that the OpenID is unique for each account and can be used for local authorization. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up an OpenID relying party, that logs the communication with the
   OpenID provider.
2. Authenticate with your Google account.
3. Look at the logs.

Comment: Thanks. Also, as I mentioned that I have to do this for a number of users (<10), do I have to ask all of them to login to this app first. Then monitor the logs, add them to the database. Sounds a bit cumbersome. Is'nt there a clearer way?

Comment: A little bit of googling (no pun intended) revealed http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/google-offers-named-openids/ to me. Maybe that article will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that Google OpenID URL is not account specific and is determined by https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id.

Details:
In the background, OpenID consumers should fetch an [XRDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XRDS) OpenID document, which is located at https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id. By parsing this document and doing the Service Discovery process, consumers will extract the Google OpenID Provider Address, which is identified by https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud.
This document tell consumers what are Google OpenID parameters. 
Below is the google XRDS document which is located at https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xrds:XRDS xmlns:xrds="xri://$xrds" xmlns="xri://$xrd*($v*2.0)">
<XRD>
<Service priority="0">
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server</Type>
<Type>http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/icon</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0</Type>
<URI>https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud</URI>
</Service>
</XRD>
</xrds:XRDS>
```